# T-SQL Script for count day

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I created a table which has this row of data:

```
WorkerID  StartDate  EndDate
========  =========  ==========
0001      2019/11/1  2019/11/2
```

When I write the day different for worker 0001 on November/2019, is pretty easy by

```
SELECT WorkerID, [WorkingDay]= DATEDIFF(day, [EndDate], [StartDate]) 
where [StartDate ] >= '2019-11-1' and EndDate <='2019-11-30'
```

however, if the record is that

```
WorkerID  StartDate   EndDate
========  =========   ==========
0001      2019/11/29  2019/12/3
```

I will want the result table as below

```
WorkerID  Workday     WorkFirstDayOfMonth
========  =========   ===================
0001      2            2019/11/1
0001      3            2019/12/1
```

Can I know how write the T-SQL query? The appropriate `where` clause is

```
where [StartDate ] >= '2019-11-1' and EndDate <='2019-12-31'
```

Comment: Will the StartDate and EndDate value ever span more than one month?

Comment: For example, will you ever have a StartDate of '2019-11-01' and an EndDate of '2020-01-05'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you probably would want an actual calendar table so you can account for weekend and holidays. But this will return the results you are looking for. I made this flexible enough to handle spanning multiple months. I am using a cte as a tally table here which makes short work of this kind of thing. Notice I added a second row for WorkerID of xxxx with multiple months.

```
declare @Something table
(
    WorkerID char(4)
    , StartDate date
    , EndDate date
)

insert @Something values
('0001', '20191129', '20191203')
, ('xxxx', '20190929', '20191203')
;

WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a cross join E1 b), 
    InlineTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E2
    )

select WorkerID
    , StartDate
    , EndDate
    , WorkDay = case when t.N = 1 --the first month
                    then datediff(day, StartDate, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, StartDate) + 1, 0)) 
                when datepart(month, dateadd(month, t.N - 1, StartDate)) < datepart(month, EndDate) --not the first OR the last month
                    then datediff(day, dateadd(month, datediff(month, t.N - 1, dateadd(month, t.N - 1, StartDate)), 0), dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, dateadd(month, t.N - 1, StartDate)) + 1, 0))
                else --the last month
                    datediff(day, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, EndDate), 0), EndDate) + 1  
                end
    , FirstDayOfMonth = convert(date, dateadd(month, datediff(month, t.N - 1, dateadd(month, t.N - 1, StartDate)), 0))
from @Something s
join InlineTally t on t.N <= datediff(month, StartDate, EndDate) + 1
order by s.WorkerID
    , t.N
```

Returns:

```
WorkerID | StartDate  | EndDate    | WorkDay | FirstDayOfMonth
0001     | 2019-11-29 | 2019-12-03 |2        | 2019-11-01
0001     | 2019-11-29 | 2019-12-03 |3        | 2019-12-01
xxxx     | 2019-09-29 | 2019-12-03 |2        | 2019-09-01
xxxx     | 2019-09-29 | 2019-12-03 |31       | 2019-10-01
xxxx     | 2019-09-29 | 2019-12-03 |30       | 2019-11-01
xxxx     | 2019-09-29 | 2019-12-03 |3        | 2019-12-01
```

Comment: Sean, it is very good script for me, that's what I want. Thank you